# tt_products imageLinkWrap typolink title for each image

Tags: image, split, typo3, title, typoscript

Iam using tt_products and trying to get a "title" param for each link to an Image, which is not provided from this extension. I have some free data-table fields left which id like to use to store the titles für each link.

This is how the Example has to look like in the Frontend after rendering each link and image.

```
<a href="Bild1.jpg" title="Titel1" rel"lightbox><img alt="" src="Bild1.jpg"></a>
<a href="Bild2.jpg" title="Titel2" rel"lightbox><img alt="" src="Bild2.jpg"></a>
<a href="Bild3.jpg" title="Titel3" rel"lightbox><img alt="" src="Bild3.jpg"></a>
```

This is the solution that i worked out till now, it loads the content from the fields but it dont split the conten of the field right and apend them to the right images

```
temp.imageLinkWrap = 1
temp.imageLinkWrap {
    stdWrap = stdWrap
    enable = 1  
    typolink {

        parameter.cObject = IMG_RESOURCE
        parameter.cObject.file.import.data = TSFE:lastImageInfo|origFile
        parameter.cObject.file.maxW = {$plugin.perfectlightbox.lightBoxMaxW}
        parameter.cObject.file.maxH = {$plugin.perfectlightbox.lightBoxMaxH}        
        parameter.override.listNum.stdWrap.data = register : IMAGE_NUM_CURRENT


        title >
        title.override.cObject = COA
        title.override.cObject {
            10 = TEXT
            10{
                data {
                    data = GP:tt_products|product
                    intval = 0
                    wrap = DB:tt_products: | :image
                }
                split{
                    token = ,
                    cObjNum = 1
                    1.current = 1
                    # for each image, add the imagecaption
                    1.wrap = |
                    1.append = TEXT
                    1.append {
                        data {
                            data = GP:tt_products|product
                            intval = 1
                            wrap = DB:tt_products: | :quality
                        }
                        # split saves the index in REGISTER:SPLIT_COUNT
                        listNum.stdWrap.data = REGISTER:SPLIT_COUNT
                        listNum.splitChar = 10
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        title.override.if.isTrue = 1
        title.insertData = 1
        parameter.cObject = IMG_RESOURCE
        parameter.cObject.file.import.data = TSFE:lastImageInfo|origFile

        ATagParams >
        ATagParams.cObject = COA
        ATagParams.cObject {
            10 = TEXT
            10.value = rel="lightbox[lb{field:uid}]"
        }

        ATagParams.insertData = 1
    }
}


    plugin.tt_products {
        templateFile = fileadmin/template/html/partial/ext/shop-tmpl.html
        pid_list = 23
        wrapInBaseClass = 0
        requiredInfoFields = agb, name, address, zip, city, email
        limitImageSingle = 6
        separateImage = 1
        listImage < .image
        listImage.file.maxW = 300
        listImage.file.maxH = 
        listImage.imageLinkWrap >
        image.wrap = <div class="img_single"> | </div>
        usePageContentImage = 0
        imageLinkWrap = 1
        image {
            altText = TEXT
            altText.data = field:title
            imageLinkWrap >
            imageLinkWrap < temp.imageLinkWrap
        }
    }
```